# Inherit plugin settings to new site in Multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite, options

I use the [Breadcrumb NavXT](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/) plugin for a WP Multisite. I activated the plugin for all sites so I can use it throughout my network.

My problem is that every time I add a new site I have to change the default settings of the plugin, but I’d like WP to use the settings I already customized for the main site because on all future sites they would be the same.

Is there a way to force WP adopting the plugin settings of the main site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice Question!

But I'll leave for the asker and for the reader the task of **finding the plugin options name**.

This can be used for any plugin/theme that relies in a *single/serialized* value in the `wp_options` table. If it's not a single value, it's another task...

In this example, I'm using [WP-Pagenavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) `option_name`.

[image: wp-pagenavi option name]

*Action hook found inside the function `wpmu_create_blog` in the file `/wp-includes/ms-functions.php`.*

```
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'wpse_70977_copy_main_site_options', 10, 6 );

function wpse_70977_copy_main_site_options( $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta )
{
    $mainsite = get_option( 'pagenavi_options' );
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    update_option( 'pagenavi_options', $mainsite );
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

This code is tested with the plugin being activated on a per site basis, and with the plugin being Network Activated.

Comment: Wow, thank you very, very much for this smart solution! It also works with the Breadcrumb NavXT plugin! The option name is `bcn_options`.

Comment: Just thought of it: this solution may present issues if the plugin/theme has some setting that points to a specific site table or has some specific site URL. In which case, *maybe* saving/updating the plugin/theme settings afterwards will correct the issue.