# How to set plugin across network in multisite and modify it in one place?

Tags: plugins, multisite

It would be convenient if I can modify a plugin in primary site, then the second site's plugin and so on will follow its modification. I know there is duplicator plugin, but that plugin need manual handling. If a user register their site, then I need to manually duplicate the plugin modification. What I want to do is, even they register their new site, the plugin will be added automatically with its modification that I did in primary site.

Comment: about which modifications are you speaking ? code modifications ? edit your question to give an example and the code you use.

Comment: Are you talking about duplicating plugin settings to other sites? Define modify?

Comment: I mean plugin settings

Comment: It has been solved. Thx guys

Comment: How did you solve it? I don't know of any good ways to do this actually. Please post an answer so people can see. Thanks.

Comment: Add function to ms-function.php like this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70977/inherit-plugin-settings-to-new-site-in-multisite

Comment: @Nikolay -- I'd recommend making use of the `*_site_option` functions (eg [`get_site_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_option/)) to store the plugin's settings (I assume it's the settings the OP wanted to update, not the plugin's code itself).